# Can I auto populate a document with child data from within the model?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema that defines an author.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const schema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {   
    fullname: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    book: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "book",
    },
}

const Authors = mongoose.model("author", schema);
module.exports = Authors;
```

Now I have a schema that defines the book.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const schema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {   
    bookname: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },

}

const Books = mongoose.model("book", schema);
module.exports = Books;
```

Normally I would use a query like
 `const author = await Author.findOne({ fullname: "bob"}).populate("book")`

Is there a way to use the author schema to auto populate the book data so I don't have to make the population on the query? I see it as way more efficient to do it in the schema than through out the code. So the final output would be from the populate/auto populate would be

```
{
  fullname: "bob",
  book: { 
           name: "joy of coding",
        },
}
```

Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

In the author model make sure you include the book model.

```js
const book = require("./book")
```

**Then you only need to add the** `pre("findOne")` **hook:**

```
schema.pre("findOne", function (next) {
  this.populate("book");
  next();
});
```

**So your query would be simply:**

```js
const author = await Author.findOne({ fullname: "bob"});
```

If you have more children to populate, you can add them to this one pre-hook, and all of the child data will be gathered and returned as one document.

Comment: The name of the pre hook "findOne" has to match the query you are doing, so this pre hook would not work for a "find" query.  You would need to create the pre hook for each kind of query you would need to make in your code.